# Number of sections in a collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have two `UICollectionViews` in a particular `UIViewController` and I wish to have a different number of sections in the two of them. I have been trying this in the following manner

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
if (collectionView == self.firstcollectionView) {
    return objects.count + 1;
   }
else
   {
    return 1;
   }
}
```

But it does not seem to work for some reason.

Also tried it with tags but haven't been able to make it work that way either.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
if (collectionView.tag == 1) {
    return objects.count + 1;
   }
else
   {
    return 1;
   }
}
```

It always shows a single section in both the `UICollectionViews` when I have been able to check that there is 1 object which should mean that there will be 2 sections in the first `UICollectionView`

UPDATE 1 : On debugging it seems the control never goes into the if-case returning 1 always.

UPDATE 2 : The if condition is where the problem is. It never gets satisfied.

UPDATE 3 : I was able to get the if-else working by declaring the `UICollectionViews` as a class variable rather than as a property. The number of sections is still 1 for both the `UICollectionViews` though.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
if (collectionView == cardscollectionView) {
    return 2;
   }
else
   {
    return 1;
   }
}
```

Still didn't work. While this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 2;
}
```

worked just fine. Just to illustrate the layouts are fine and 2 cells do show up in both the collection views.

SAMPLE PROJECT (On huge demand :D) -

https://github.com/genaks/UIICollectionView-Sections

I have not yet gone to the extent of reloading the UICollectionView as the current setup hasn't been working altogether

Comment: once check the reference link from xib , is it connected properly or not?

Comment: It is.. The cell loads up just fine.. It's the number of sections that's getting messed up

Comment: yes, your condition  if (collectionView == self.firstcollectionView) is okay , i think it is not referenced from xib

Comment: I was able to debug that the control never goes into the if-case

Comment: are you given link from xib collectionview to self.firstcollectionView properly?

Comment: I have declared the collectionview in my code and not through XIB

Comment: if you set the tag in `UICollectionView` from storyboard or coding way?

Comment: @IyyappanRavi in my code

Comment: show me allocation of collecttionviews and delegate setting

Comment: Can you give a code of declaration of the collection view?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionView *cardscollectionView;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you have set delegate and data source to self for both collection views like

```
   self.firstcollectionView.delegate = self;
   self.firstcollectionView.datasource = self;
```

And same for second collectionview also.

And make sure that you have connected your outlet properly.

or

Make sure that you are setting tag properly

**Update:**

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {

if (collectionView == self.cardscollectionView) {

    NSLog(@"getting called. It is cardcollerctionView");
    return 2;

}
if (collectionView == self.bankscollectionView) {
    NSLog(@"getting called. it is bankcollectionView");
    return 1;
}

else
{
    return 1;


}

    //use above or below both are working fine.
    //******************************* OR ********************************************

    if (collectionView == self.cardscollectionView) {

        NSLog(@"getting called. It is cardcollerctionView");
        return 2;

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"it is else");
        return 1;


    }

 }
```

I have run your demo and it's work fine. I have updated answer with `numberofsection` method. both portion of code is working. Make sure that you are not using same `UICollectionViewLayout` for both `collectionViews`

Hope this will help :)

Comment: [self.firstcollectionView setDataSource:self];
        [self.firstcollectionView setDelegate:self];
should do the same right?

Comment: Yes , That is same. put break point in delegate and data source method and debug and check that it is got called or not. print datasource where needed. make sure that `objects.count` is not 0

Comment: objects.count is 1. It is 0 initially but it's 1 after I load the elements from web

Comment: numberOfSectionsInCollectionView gets called but the if condition never gets satisfied making the control go to the else block always

Comment: That means there is problem in `collectionView == self.firstcollectionView`. that only happen when your datasource is not get colled for `firstcollectionView`

Comment: I have double-checked for the data source and the delegates @Lion. They are both set for both the collection views

Comment: Have you check that your outlets are properly connected with appropriate collection view in interface builder ?

Comment: The if condition is where the problem is. It never gets satisfied

Comment: You are doing some simple mistake definitely, now what is it that only you can identify!! or upload one demo with  same  setup you have made

Comment: I have uploaded a sample project. Link in the question above.

Comment: Your project is empty man. It have just story board and default view controller which comes by default when create new project.

Comment: Opps. Should be there now

Answer (score 0):

I think you will not set tag properly,First the set the Tag in your viewDidLoad: method, example is below,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // put your code...
    firstCollectionView.tag = 10000;
    secondCollectioView.tag = 9000;
}
```

or set the tag in storyboard is below,

[image]

then you will check the condition are

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    if (collectionView.tag == 9000) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return objects.count + 1;;
    }

}
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work. Try it.

```
 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView
 {
      if([collectionView isEqual:self.firstcollectionView]){
          //return object count for firstCollectionView;
      }
      else if([collectionView isEqual:self.secondCollectionView])
      {
          //return object count for secondCollectionView;
      } 
 }
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't

Comment: @genaks check if you have set the data source for both collection Views

Comment: I have set for both the collection views Sushree

Comment: @genaks can you just remove both the collection Views and add them again. Then set their datasource. Clean the code before you run.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial method of checking the `UICollectionView`s identity without tags does work and is more robust than using tags but if the objects count is 0 then the sections count will still be the same. You mentioned the count is initially 0 then 1 after the elements load from the web. Are you calling `reloadData()` on the collectionViews after the web load has completed?.

Here's a complete working example of having two `UICollectionView`s created in code (without any web fetching) that works with different section counts:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {}

class DoubleViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

var firstCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let v = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    return v
}()

var secondCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let v = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    return v
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(self.firstCollectionView)
    self.view.addSubview(self.secondCollectionView)
    self.firstCollectionView.delegate = self
    self.secondCollectionView.delegate = self
    self.firstCollectionView.dataSource = self
    self.secondCollectionView.dataSource = self
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    if collectionView == self.firstCollectionView {
        return 1
    }
    return 2
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.backgroundColor = randomColor()
    return cell
}

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()
    self.firstCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor).active = true
    self.firstCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor).active = true
    self.firstCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.secondCollectionView.topAnchor).active = true
    self.firstCollectionView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true
    self.secondCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).active = true
    self.secondCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor).active = true
    self.secondCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor).active = true
    self.firstCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.secondCollectionView.heightAnchor).active = true
  }
}
```

The extra constraint code is needed since your not using xibs/storyboards

Comment: I have called reloadData() after I have loaded my data from the web.

Comment: Are you saying you were already calling `reloadData()` and it didn't make a difference or you have tried it now and it made now difference? My answer above is a working sample and does provide difference section counts for each collectionview. If your still having trouble then the problem is due to something you have not explained in your current setup.

Comment: I have been calling reloadData() from the time of posting this question. I will try and post a sample of what I've been doing

Comment: I have uploaded a sample project. The link is in the original question above

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
  if([collectionView isEqual: collectionView1])
  {
    return CollectionArray1.count;
  }
  else if ([collectionView isEqual: collectionView2])
  {
    return CollectionArray2.count;
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"Dummy Text");
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,your `cardscollectionView` had changed before perform `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` or you set delegate in the wrong way.

Add follow code to check if two collectionViews 's delegate is `self`.

The correct log is ***two different***  `collectionView` address and ***only one*** `cardscollectionView` address.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    NSLog(@"collectionView=%@", collectionView);
    NSLog(@"cardscollectionView=%@", cardscollectionView);
    if (collectionView == cardscollectionView) {
        return 2;
    } else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using the same UICollectionViewLayout for both the UICollectionViews. Using 2 different UICollectionViewLayouts solved the problem for me. Thanks for the help everyone. I was about to go crazy with this.