# 2 UICollectionViews on a single UIViewController with a different number of sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Is it possible to have 2 `UICollectionViews` in a single `UIViewController` with a different number of sections. I have tried doing this in the following manner -

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView 
{
    if (collectionView == cardscollectionView) 
    {
       return 2;
    }

    else
    {
       return 1;
    }
}
```

But it does not seem to work. Both the `UICollectionViews` end up having a single section. Pretty similar to what I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560006/number-of-sections-in-a-collection-view).

Comment: Whats the issue ??? Looks correct

Comment: both the collection views end up having 1 section

Comment: why are you asking basically the same question again? consider using child view controllers...

Comment: Have you tried using CollectionView tag?

Comment: @wain : I respect your opinion to use childViewControllers but wont it be heavy It can be achieved with singleViewController

Comment: @Wain I thought the problem is now different to what had been described there and qualified to be asked as a different question.

Comment: @genaks : Have you properly initialized cardscollectionView variable ??? I could see your update as it never enters if condition

Comment: @Bhumika I have tried the tags as well. It does not seem to be a problem though as the if-else condition seems to be working fine.

Comment: child VCs are about compartmentalisation and separation of concerns... tell us how you're testing and what the numbers of rows are set to

Comment: @SandeepBhandari yes. The cells show up fine as well.

Comment: @genaks : Please provide a lttle more code like how are you initializing the collectionView updating your variable , setting delegate and data source for both collectionView

Comment: @Wain I have set up breakpoints at the numberOfSectionsInCollectionView method and the cellForItemAtIndexPath. The numberOfSectionsInCollectionView gets called twice after I reload both my collection views. The cellForItemAtIndexPath gets called only twice as well while it should have been called thrice

Comment: why - how many items fit onto the screen at that point in time? what are the layouts, custom or flow? there are so many factors potentially affecting this and all you're looking at is one tiny little bit...

Comment: @Wain screen space is not, according to me, a problem. I tried and return 2 in the numberOfSectionsInCollectionView and both the collection views has 2 sections each

Comment: you're going to keep on getting the same answer from people no matter how many times you write this question, and some other random guesses, because that's pretty much all anyone can say based on the information available - please use child view controllers

Comment: @Wain thought so. Thanks

Comment: If possible then make demo and upload it as i have said in other question also!! because it should be very silly mistake!

Comment: @Lion Alright. I will try and write a demo and upload it as soon as I get the chance

Answer (score 0):

Please create two different object of two collectionview
And try following code

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView
 {
  if([collectionView isEqual:self.firstcollectionView]){
      //return object count for firstCollectionView;
  }
  else if([collectionView isEqual:self.secondCollectionView])
  {
      //return object count for secondCollectionView;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that the case where you expect your if statement would be true, it's not.

How did you create the outlet to your cardscollectionview?
If there is a @property of this cardscollectionview your should use something like:

```
if (collectionView == self.cardscollectionView) {
    return 2;
   }
else
   {
    return 1;
   }
}
```

And I am not sure what your other collection view variable name is, let's assume its called otherCollectionView, then in my opinion the following would not work either, i suspect both views to have 3 sections with this code:

```
if (collectionView == cardscollectionView) {
    return 2;
   }
else if(collectionView == otherCollectionView)
   {
    return 1;
   }
}else{
    return 3;
}
```

First check to see if cardscollectionview is actually something and not some uninitialized  variable (nil). You could try and use tags to solve your problem but the whole purpose of this method giving you the sender (collectionView) is for you to determine which one we are talking about here.

As for my awnser, change cardscollectionView to self.cardsCollectionView

Comment: The cardscollectionview is not nil as I can check while debugging. My collection views are declared as a class variable and not as properties

Comment: why would they be defined as class variables?

Comment: instance variable*